# How to determine MTU between my cable modem and ISP?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, mtu

I am trying to understand the "big picture" of MTU. Specifically, many discussions of MTU focus on a single hop (e.g. laptop to router), so the natural question is: how to determine MTU between cable modem and ISP, or more generally, for any given hop of a route.

Now, I can easily see the MTU between my laptop and its: wi-fi router using ifconfig on Mac OS X:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=2b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,TSO4>
ether 58:b0:35:f0:14:75 
media: autoselect (none)
status: inactive    
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 58:b0:35:72:64:fa 
inet6 fe80::5ab0:35ff:fe72:64fa%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
inet 192.168.1.100 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
media: autoselect
status: active
```

1500 is the canonical value b/c of the limitation of the wi-fi frame (which I am guessing was designed to match the Ethernet frame; please correct me if that's wrong).

So, the question is: **How to determine the MTU of arbitrary hops in my route?**

**Answer summary:**

Per the below answer, best bet is "tcpdump", "traceroute --mtu" or "tracepath"

Comment: Are you looking for Path MTU Discovery (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery)?

Comment: Yes! Looks like what I was after, more or less (ultimately it's the end-to-end MTU that counts). Feel free to upgrade your comment to a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is [**Path MTU Discovery**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery). You can see that in action with [**`tcpdump(1)`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tcpdump.1.html) during [TCP three way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_handshake#Connection_establishment) by watching the [MSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_handshake#Maximum_segment_size) option values (you will need appropriate level of dump verbosity, afair `-vv` does it).

Original [**`traceroute(8)`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/traceroute.8.html) is supposed to show you path MTU changes, but I never had luck with it. Linux [**`tracepath(8)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tracepath) gives you hop MTU value right away.

Comment: Thanks for the tracepath tip; it's a great tool.